# WSO2 DSS Cannot execute SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We are in the process of upgrading WSO2 DSS from version 2.5.1 to 2.6.3.  In version 2.5.1, we were able to execute stored procedures from our SQL Server 2005 database via services with no problems whatsoever.  However, in this new version, that is not the case.  When trying to execute a stored procedure in the TryIt window, an error is logged stating

ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet} -    {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet} java.lang.AbstractMethodError

followed by a complete stack trace

If I change the query to a select statement, it works just fine.

Maybe there is some setting now that is needed prior to running stored procedures?  Maybe it's another configuration issue?  Hopefully someone can assist with this problem.  I like the enhancements offered by this new version, but if we can't run stored procedures, it's not a viable option for us.  Thanks in advance!

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not actually posted the method they are complaining in the AbstractMethodError. But I'm guessing this is something to do with a JDBC driver which is not JDBC4 compliant. With Java 6, we are using JDBC4 features in WSO2 DSS, so you would have to upgrade to proper JDBC4 drivers, which is in MSSQL's case, would be the SQLJDBC4 driver. Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: Updating the JDBC driver did the trick!  Thanks so much for the quick reply.